# Implementing MCMC

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo

I'm writing an MCMC algorithm in R and I'm wondering about the following: say we have two parameters, $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$. I want to update each one at a time from the corresponding posterior conditional distributions. Say $\theta_1^{(0)}$ and $\theta_2^{(0)}$ are the initial values. Then at iteration 1 I update first $\theta_1$ from

$\theta_1^{(1)} \sim f(\theta_1 | \theta_2^{(0)}, \text{Data})$

Now when updating $\theta_2$, I should use

$\theta_2^{(1)} \sim f(\theta_2 | \theta_1^{(1)}, \text{Data})$

Is there a theoretical problem if when updating $\theta_2$ I use $\theta_1^{(0)}$ I instead of $\theta_1^{(1)}$? That is

$\theta_2^{(1)} \sim f(\theta_2 | \theta_1^{(0)}, \text{Data})$?

Comment: Not exactly related, but I wouldn't use MCMC for a two parameter problem. Quadrature would be much better.

Comment: @probabilityislogic when first learning MCMC it's often worth starting on problems you can check the answers to.

Comment: @Glen_b - I take your point, but there's nothing explicitly in the question that says this is a pure learning exercise.  If it is a "real" problem, then mcmc would be crazy for a two parameter problem.  MCMC should always be the method of last resort imo.

Comment: @probabilityislogic MCMC works fine for arbitrary number of parameters. Otherwise hierarchical models wouldn't work very well, since you generally need to track the posteriors for multiple parameters at each level of the model. Hell, bayesian linear regression wouldn't work either sinec you'd need to track the posterior of each coefficient.

Comment: @DavidMarx I think probabilityislogic is suggesting that it is better to use MCMC on large problems rather than very small problems that can be done to high accuracy in other ways.

Comment: Dimitris - it might look like the two answers you have so far disagree, but it's not actually the case; they simply interpret the implications of your question differently. Mine takes your question to refer *only* to the first iterate, the other takes the same scheme to refer to all subsequent iterates as well.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity in my question. In my actual problem I have more than 1000 parameters, so MCMC is the way to go. Regarding the posterior conditionals, my intention (motivated by making the code much faster) was to use the same scheme for all subsequent iterations. Clearly this is wrong as explained...

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is a big problem with that. You don't have the correct stationary distribution anymore when you do that. The relevant question to ask is whether the transition kernel leaves the posterior *invariant* i.e. $\int K(\theta \mid \theta^{old}) p(\theta^{old}) \ d\theta^{old} = p(\theta)$. The transition kernel you are proposing is
$$
K(\theta_1, \theta_2 \mid \theta_1^{old}, \theta_2^{old})
= p(\theta_1 \mid \theta_2^{old}, y) p(\theta_2 | \theta_1^{old}, y).
$$
This does not leave the posterior $p(\theta_1, \theta_2 \mid y)$ invariant:
$$
\int \int p(\theta_1\mid\theta_2^{old}, y) p(\theta_2\mid\theta_1^{old}, y) p(\theta_1^{old}, \theta_2^{old} \mid y) \ d\theta_1^{old} d\theta_2^{old}
\ne p(\theta_1, \theta_2 \mid y).
$$
Actually, it leaves a different distribution invariant: 
$$
\int\int p(\theta_1\mid\theta_2^{old}, y) p(\theta_2\mid\theta_1^{old}, y) p(\theta_2^{old}\mid y)p(\theta_1^{old}\mid y) \ d\theta_1^{old}d\theta_2^{old}
= p(\theta_1\mid y)p(\theta_2 \mid y)
$$ 
which is not the target. Hence none of the usual theory applies - actually, it seems to me like you will effectively be running two separate, correct, Gibbs samplers so in some sense you could still use the output if you ran this chain but it would be with a different justification and it might not extend to $3$ or more parameters. Compare with the correct transition kernel, $K(\theta_1, \theta_2 \mid \theta_1^{old}, \theta_2^{old}) = p(\theta_1 \mid \theta_2)p(\theta_2 \mid \theta_1^{old})$:
$$
\int \int p(\theta_1\mid\theta_2, y) p(\theta_2\mid\theta_1^{old}, y) p(\theta_1^{old}, \theta_2^{old} \mid y) \ d\theta_2^{old} d\theta_1^{old} \\
= p(\theta_1\mid\theta_2, y) \int p(\theta_1^{old}, \theta_2 \mid y) \ d\theta_1^{old} \\
= p(\theta_1\mid \theta_2, y) p(\theta_2 \mid y) = p(\theta_1, \theta_2 \mid y)
$$

Answer (score 3):

For that first iterate? That shouldn't matter, since in effect it just affects your starting point - as long as subsequently you sample correctly, everything should still work as intended - the convergence still works and so on. (It's useless but should be harmless.)

If after that first time through, your scheme is doing one of these:

(1)
 $\theta_1^{(i+1)} \sim f(\theta_1 | \theta_2^{(i)}, \text{Data})$

$\quad\,\,\theta_2^{(i+1)} \sim f(\theta_2 | \theta_1^{(i+1)}, \text{Data})$

OR

(2)
$\theta_2^{(i+1)} \sim f(\theta_2 | \theta_1^{(i)}, \text{Data})$

$\quad\,\,\theta_1^{(i+1)} \sim f(\theta_1 | \theta_2^{(i+1)}, \text{Data})$

then you have a Gibbs sampler and from the convergence of the Markov Chain to its stationary distribution, you'll in the long run be sampling from $f(\theta_1 , \theta_2| \text{Data})$. It shouldn't matter that you did something nonstandard on the first step.